# Online Google Docs Alternative for Java Coding

Tags: java, github, bitbucket, google-docs

I have a coding team and we are all working on the same project because of time issues. I'm looking for a real time editor like "Google Docs" but for coding Java. I want to be able to see code being added by another user without refreshing the page.

I'm pretty sure GitHub is able to do that but I'm a teenager and can't really afford paying 10$ a month for a private repository. I don't know if bitbucket can do this.

Anyone knows either a program or a website that corresponds to what I am looking for?

Comment: In practice, you probably don't want this. Partition the work so that team members are working on *different* source files, at which point standard source-control mechanisms should suffice.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @OliCharlesworth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have multiple team members working on the same codebase you need source control. They should all be able to write code from their own computer and save it to a central repository. When team member A edits foo.java and then team member b edits foo.java the changes are both saved. A good free source control system is Subversion.

You should google "Source Control" and spend 10 minutes giving it a read.

Comment: Do you have an example software i could use?

Comment: You're question asks about multiple developers working on the same project,  subversion (just to name one free source control system)  will allow you do do that. Multiple people editing the same file at the same time is common, but not in the way you are suggesting. Thats just not how software is developed,  and for good reason.